# map/reduce/filter on a linked list... failing at map! (in C)

Tags: c, pointers, mapreduce

So here's my code... My understanding is that I'm supposed to create a function "map" that takes a function as an argument.  It's not going as planned.  Any help would be completely amazing.

Here's a compilable (well not compilable, but scaled down) version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
//it should be apparent that I am quite new to C, I have some java experience.
struct linkedList {
   int count;
   int num;
   struct linkedList *next;
};
struct linkedList *head, *tail, *curr;
int count1=0;
int i=0;

int square(int v) {return v=v*v;}

void map(int (*func)(int v), struct linkedList){
    struct linkedList2 *head, *tail, *curr;
    for(curr=head; curr!=NULL; curr=curr->next){
        curr->num=func(curr->num);
        printList();
    }
}

void start(){
    printf("This program will ONLY accept integer input.\n");
    head=NULL;
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        count1++;
        curr=malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        curr->count=count1;
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &curr->num);
        if(head==NULL) { head=curr; }
        else { tail->next=curr; }
        tail=curr;
        tail->next=NULL;
    }
    printf("A list has been created.\n");
}

void printList(){
    printf("The list now contains these numbers: ");
    for(curr=head;curr!=NULL;curr=curr->next){
        printf("%d, ", curr->num);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

 start();
 printList();

 map(square, linkedList);
 printList();
 system("PAUSE");   
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 just for using map/reduce in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining all of those structs and functions inside of `main` is not how you're supposed to write C.  Move the `int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {` to right after the definition of `printList` so that `main` only contains the actual code for `main`.

Moreover, your definition of `map` appears to have an unfinished prototype.  Instead of `void map(int (*func)(int v), struct linkedList)`, in which the second parameter is unused, you want `void map(int (*func)(int v), struct linkedList* head)` (and then get rid of the declaration of `head` on the next line).  Moreover, `linkedList2` here presumably should be changed to `linkedList`.  In addition, your attempt to call `map` in `main` with `map(square, linkedList)` is nonsensical; you want to use `map(square, head)`.

Comment: This was my first question, and I am taken back by the speed and accuracy of your response.  Thanks so much.  Answer checked, but unfortunately I dont have the rep to upvote.  Thanks again.